VoiceNextClient App does not respond when bot tries to join channel
Im making a discord bot using DSharpplus + VoiceNextClient. I want to make my bot able to join channel which I'm connected with.
Tried to do it like that:
[SlashCommand("join", "Makes the bot join your vc")]
public async Task Join(InteractionContext ctx)
{
    var channel = ctx.Member?.VoiceState?.Channel;
    if (channel == null)
        throw new Exception();

    VoiceNextConnection connection = await channel.ConnectAsync(); // error here

    var outputEmbed = new DiscordEmbedBuilder
    {
        Color = DiscordColor.Green,
        Title = "Bot notification",
        Description = $"Successfully joined to a channel",
    };

    var message = new DiscordMessageBuilder().AddEmbed(outputEmbed);

    await ctx.Channel.SendMessageAsync(message);
}

Bot joins the channel correctly but on the returned embed I can see that application does not respond. If i delete line
VoiceNextConnection connection = await channel.ConnectAsync();

I can see embed successfully but obviously bot doesn't join channel. What should I do ? I have aready done some research but I haven't found solution yet.
